# How to use Kibana4 dashboards for multiple indexes

Tags: indexing, dashboard, kibana-4

All,

I have created a dashboard for one of the index in kibana4. Can I use the same dashboard for multiple indexes ?? Is there any provision for the same?

The indexes are :

```
Index Patterns 

[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
[dev-logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
[prod-logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
[test-legacy-logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
[test-logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your visualization, you specify which index you'd like to use.  With this, you can have visualizations from multiple indexes on your dashboard at the same time.

Now, if you want to have a single visualization run against multiple indexes, you'll want an [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).